# find state name from lat-long in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a `pyspark` data frame df which is holding large no of rows.Once of the columns is lat-long.
I want to find the state name from the lat-long.I am using the below code

```
import reverse_geocoder as rg
new_df = df_new2.toPandas()
list_long_lat = a["lat_long"].tolist() 
result = rg.search(list_long_lat)
state_name=[]
for each_entry in result:
    state_name.append(each_entry["admin2"])
state_values = pd.Series(state_name)
a.insert(loc=0, column='State_name', value=state_values)
```

first of all when converting to pandas I am getting out of memory issue.Is there any way to efficiently find the state name with out even converting from pyspark data frame to pandas data frame considering the no of rows in input data frame is huge:1000000 Million

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try by creating a udf

```
import reverse_geocoder as rg
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
map_state = f.udf(lambda x : rg.search(x)[0]['admin2'])
data.withColumn('State',map_state(f.col('lat_long'))).show()
```

The only drawback here is udf are not very fast also this will hit the api multiple times.

Comment: yes, I tried like this before, it's too much time consuming. That's why I went with converting to pandas dataframe.For small dataset it's running fine but for larger dataset giving OO memory issue.

Comment: Have you counted the distinct lat-long values

Comment: Actually lat_long values are coming directly from the dataset.I didn't count.But in most cases lat_long are almost same. Beacuse this lat_long are basically tells where a particular car was driven throughout the day

Comment: What you can do, if the lat-long are mostly same then just collect those latlong and pass to the api then create a map which will add a column in existing df this will be really fast if the number of distinct latlong are considerable

Answer (score 0):

Didn't do much pyspark, but pyspark's syntax is somewhat similar to pandas. Maybe give the following snippet a try.

```py
search_state_udf = udf(lambda x: rg.search(x), StringType())

df.withColumn("state", search_state_udf(df.lat_long))
```

When the dataset is more than 1M records, looping the whole dataset is often not performant, you may want to have a look at `apply` to make it efficient.